# Is there any document about using Python preprocess with h2o steam?

Tags: h2o

The h2o steam website said Python preprocess with pojo
As .War is an optional, but I can not find any examples about doing this step by step,
Where can I find out more details about this? Or I better do it in Java only?

The situation is I have one python preprocess program, mainly use pandas to do some data munging before calling h2o to train/score the model. I want to use the 
h2o steam as the score engine. The website mentions I can wrap the python and h2o pojo/mojo file together as a .war file, so I can call it through REST API.  But I 
can not find example or details about how to proceed. Also do I need to and if yes how to include these 
python library like pandas in the war file?

Comment: Please rephrase your question, and explain clearly what you are trying to do.  It is not clear.